# Intellij: Markdown Visual Guide Columns Are Missing

Tags: intellij-idea

When editing markdown files in intellij, I am not seeing the visual guide for columns at 80 and 120.

In `Preferences | Editor | Code Style`, I have `Visual Guides: 80,120`.

Is there another setting that I need to enable?

I'm using Intellij Ultimate 2018.1.5.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/EfvZFxD.png) with the [bundled Markdown plug-in](https://i.imgur.com/vJ13wUP.png).

Answer (score 1):

I saw a thread elsewhere where someone was having a similar problem, and it turned out their color scheme meant they couldn't see the visual guide:

> Please check whether Setting | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Right margin is a color that's visible against your editor background.

[source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206070859-How-do-I-enable-the-80-column-guideline-)